# rake db:create works, rails dbconsole works, rake db:migrate/db:seed

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

When I try to use a rake task that isn't `rake db:create` that uses a DB connection (ie `rake db:migrate`)
`Connection refused - sendto(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 9999`

Inexplicably, it tries to connect on non-default port (`9999`) that, as far as I can tell, not in the config (ie `config/database.yaml`) . When I change MySQL to use this port, I get a slightly different error: `Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)`

MySQL server is a vanilla homebrew install, if that matters (whole thing is running on MacOS 10.12.3)

Comment: Is it possible that the user you're using doesn't have access to read the database you created?

Comment: Unless it's using a user that isn't in the config, no. I'm able to connect to the server with `mysql <dbname> -u <username>` with the info in config/database.yaml.